# Cannot instantiate objects with a parent which is persistent. New object will be created without a parent. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, persistence, instantiation

Im getting a Transform, its not null, its not disabled in scene, it should work, but it doesnt..

```
        public void SetupSelectionPanel(AccountData accountData)
    {
        selectionPanel = transform.Find("Selection_Panel");
        logoutButton = transform.Find("Bttn_LogOut").GetComponent<Button>();
        if (accountData == null)
        {
            print("accountData is null");
            return;
        }
        if (accountData.Players == null)
        {
            print("accountData.Players is null");
            return;
        }
        foreach (PlayerData pd in accountData.Players)
        {
            GameObject uiPlayerObj = Instantiate(uiPlayerContentPrefab, selectionPanel);
            // Error happens on above line, uiPlayerObj gets instantiated in scene without a parent as Console error says.. No idea why though.

            UIPlayerSelect uiPlayer = uiPlayerObj.GetComponent<UIPlayerSelect>();
            uiPlayer.Init(pd);
        }

        logoutButton.onClick.AddListener(() =>
                        {
                            LogoutAccount();
                        });
    }
```

Console error:

```
Cannot instantiate objects with a parent which is persistent. New object will be created without a parent.

  UnityEngine.Object:Instantiate<UnityEngine.GameObject> (UnityEngine.GameObject,UnityEngine.Transform)
  AccountUI.UIPlayerSelectPanel:SetupSelectionPanel (AccountData) (at Assets/Scripts/Client/UI/UIPlayerSelectPanel.cs:34)
```

Ive tried a lot of things to no avail.

Its not a prefab that im trying to use as a parent.

It is however an UI element that im trying to instantiate.

After it is instantiated in the scene (with no parent) I can drag it under the correct parent using the editor, while playmode is still going, without any problems, so there should actually be nothing stopping it.

Setting manually after instantiating:

```
   uiPlayerObj.transform.SetParent(selectionPanel);
```

Gives the following error:

```
Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'Bttn_PlayerSelect(Clone)').
```

But its not a prefab? Yes the UI Canvas + Selection Panel im trying to use as a parent here is instantiated from a Prefab at Game Start. But it is now a Scene Object and not a prefab? Why is Unity considering this instantiated scene object as a prefab???
Thank you.

Edit:
Playmode Image:
[image]

Comment: Why are you instantiating a UI prefab? Isn't it easier to just always create it and have it enabled/disabled depending on use case? For example the registration / login panel can be identical, but the "confirm password" textbox would only be visible when registering, not for login. However, as an object it can always exist, just show it or hide it depending on the context.

Comment: It even seems to be part of the scene already anyway ... so why are you trying to instantiate it again?

Comment: So the reason for this error is that it was Instantiated? Why? And why can I drag children under it and use it as a parent by dragging and dropping objects in the Hierarchy? Why wouldnt it work through code if it works manually by dragging and dropping? Is it a bug or intended? if intended then why!?